# make relative string as per selected options from checkboxlist in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am making practise management system where I need to add feature where a clinic or hospital can add visiting doctors in their clinics or hospitals. Below is mu current interface.[image]

Here clinic or hospital selects day & put time so all selected days gets that time. Now I want to make a string in which values gets stored like this

Mon,Wed,Fri
10.00am - 2.00pm

I can able to perform above string with this code

```
string selectedDays = string.Empty;
foreach (ListItem chk in daySelect.Items) {
    if (chk.Selected == true) {
        selectedDays += chk.Text + ",";
    }
}

string vistingDays = string.Empty;
vistingDays = selectedDays + "<br />" + frmTime.SelectedValue.ToString + "-" + ToTime.SelectedValue.ToString;
```

And if days selected on continuous basis i.e. Mon Tue Wed Thu then it should get string values like this. Here only difference is if they selected more than 2 days which comes continuous then instead of comma it gets dash as separator.

Mon - Thu 
10.00am - 02.00pm

I want help to perform above operation with my code. Please forgive if my post is complicated the way I posted here but I really need help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most readable solution but it works,if anyone has some kind of clever solution using LINQ or less code I would love to see it but if nobody else answers you're welcome to use my code, just test it properly for all possible scenarios:

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string selectedDays = String.Empty;
    int j = 0;

    var items = new Dictionary<int,string>();

    for (int i = 0; i < daySelect.Items.Count; i++)
        items.Add(i, daySelect.Items[i].Selected ? daySelect.Items[i].Text : "");

    for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++ )
    {
        string current = items.ElementAt(i).Value;

        if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedDays))
        {
            j = items.ElementAt(i).Key;
            selectedDays = current;
            continue;
        }
        else if(current != "")
        {
            if((j + 1) == i)
            {
                int lastComma = selectedDays.LastIndexOf(',');
                int lastDash = selectedDays.LastIndexOf('-');

                if ((selectedDays.Contains('-') && !selectedDays.Contains(',')) || lastDash > lastComma)
                {
                    string day = selectedDays.Substring(selectedDays.LastIndexOf('-') + 1, 3);
                    selectedDays = selectedDays.Replace(day, current);
                }
                else
                    selectedDays += ("-" + current);

                j = items.ElementAt(i).Key;
            }
            else
            {
                selectedDays += "," + current;
                j = items.ElementAt(i).Key;
            }
        }
    }

    string vistingDays = selectedDays + "<br />" + frmTime.SelectedValue.ToString() + "-" + ToTime.SelectedValue.ToString();
}
```